# Issues using T4 to generate basic Assembly Information

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, t4

I'm having issues just creating the most basic of `Assembly Information` using T4 - can anyone give me a hand?

I simply want the code below to generate a version number, manually so I can see that it works but the compiled `.cs` file doesn't have the information it should.

Here's the code:

#### SharedAssemblyInfo.tt

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    int major    = 5;
    int minor    = 0;
    int build    = 0;
    int revisions = 0;

    // TODO: Write code here to automatically generate a version

    string version = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
                                   major,
                                   minor,
                                   build,
                                   revisions);
#>
// This code was generated by a tool. Any changes made manually will be lost
// the next time this code is regenerated.

using System.Reflection;


[assembly: AssemblyVersion("<#= version #>")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("<#= version #>")]
```

Here's the expected result:

#### SharedAssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("5.0.0.0")]
```

And here's the [actual result](https://gist.github.com/PrestonII/0585eb586f70d5d42b71554177fae676) - which does not have any of the assembly code above.

This is similar to a few questions I've reviewed like these: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909922/reflection-with-t4-get-assemblies), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298121/t4-toolbox-referencing-class-in-current-assembly) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/t4-assembly-directive?view=vs-2017) but even following their specific use cases, I've not been able to produce a .cs file that has the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion attributes I'm expecting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have an auto incrementing version number (Visual Studio)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio)

Comment: I've already reviewed that and a few other posts @Kenneth K. should I include the in the question ?

Comment: The way this is usually done is using a utility that modifies an already-existing AssemblyInfo file.  MSBuild has such a step (`AssemblyInfoTask`).  My instincts tell me using T4 for this won't work as expected.  If you use Git, `GitVersion` supports automatically updating the AssemblyInfo as well.

Comment: Man @Amy, I'd never even heard of Got version but that seems perfect! Can you put that as an answer so I can accept it ? I'll modify the question to deal more abstractedly with handling "versioning"

Answer (score 1):

From the output, it looks like you have the .tt file configured as a [runtime file generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017#run-time-t4-text-templates) rather than a design time generator.

Check the *Custom Tool* property for the file. It should be *TextTemplateFileGenerator*, not *TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor*:

[image]